# How do I avoid writing a SQL Server query twice to avoid duplication?

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I have an sql query that requires repeating the same `SELECT` statement a number of times within the overall query as input to other calculations.

How can I write the query so that I only define the repeated `SELECT` SQL statement once? Is there a method for doing this to avoid making mistakes when it is repeated through the query?

UPDATE: 
in this instance the data returned from the SELECT is expected to be < 100 rows in 80% of cases and max of 100-200 rows in the other 20% of cases

CTE and table variables both look like valid answers - but how do you know which one is the more appropriate option in any situation?

Comment: @ypercube - `CTE` isn't a good fit here since it's only around for one query.  Once I `SELECT * FROM CTE` the next query can't see it unless I redefine the CTE which kind of defeats the purpose :)

Comment: @JNK: In that case, a View may be handy. I thought the OP wanted to use the same SELECT multiple times in the same query.

Comment: He might be, it's not really clear tbh.

Comment: @ypercube: You are correct - I want to reuse the same SELECT multiple times in the same query so CTE is a good fit. If you add your suggestion as an actual answer, I will mark it as the correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to reuse the same `SELECT` as a subquery, multiple times in the same query, then you can use **[Common Table Expressions (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)**.

Answer (score 7):

Use the select to insert into a Temp table or table variable. (Use table variable if you think the data set will be small, temp table if it will be large). Then in all subsequent queries join to the temp table or table variable just like any other table.

Comment: Other considerations - temp tables can be indexed and have constraints, which variables cannot.  Temp tables are also visible in inner scopes, and table variables only in the immediate scope.

Comment: Table variables do have less potential for tempdb locking and concurrency issues, though.  It's not always a clear-cut choice.